# mondrian mdx filter a set on year level in a date dimension

Tags: mdx, mondrian

mdx newbie.
I have a query which has a date dimension. Years are integers and are in the level CalYear. 
I'm using Mondrian (via Pentaho)

How do I show years after 2012? The data years with integer values 2012, 2013, 2014.
It is a Time dimension; this level is a Year.

If I start from this query:

```
SELECT
     [Measures].[SalesMonth] ON COLUMNS,
    {[YearMonth.CalYearMonth].CalYear.members} ON ROWS
    FROM [mt_report]
```

I get a result of three rows.

I try this:

```
SELECT
    [Measures].[SalesMonth] ON COLUMNS,
    Filter({[YearMonth.CalYearMonth].CalYear.members},
[YearMonth.CalYearMonth].CalYear.CurrentMember.Value > 0) ON ROWS
    FROM [mt_report]
```

and it returns all data (same as the first query)

but

```
   SELECT
     [Measures].[SalesMonth] ON COLUMNS,
    Filter({[YearMonth.CalYearMonth].CalYear.members},
[YearMonth.CalYearMonth].CalYear.CurrentMember.Value > 9999) ON ROWS
    FROM [mt_report]
```

but this also returns the same.

---

This works ...

```
Filter({[YearMonth.CalYearMonth].[CalYear].Members},
[YearMonth.CalYearMonth].[CalYear].CurrentMember.name > '2012')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MDX you can use the [range operator](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Range.html), with a NULL as a second parameter :

If  [YearMonth].[2012] is the member for 2012 :

```
SELECT
  [YearMonth].[Year].[2013]:NULL on 0
...
```

The same using 2012 and using the [nextMember](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/NextMember.html) MDX function.

```
SELECT
  [YearMonth].[Year].[2012].nextMember:NULL on 0
...
```

Comment: On Mondrian, it returns nothing. This was reported as a bug but basically marked "won't fix". http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/MONDRIAN-264.

But using your idea, this works for Mondrian:

SELECT
{[Measures].[SalesMonth]} ON COLUMNS,

[YearMonth.CalYearMonth].[CalYear].[2013] : [YearMonth.CalYearMonth].[CalYear].[2013].LastSibling on rows
from [mt_report]